# Callback not being called Python

Tags: python, macos, callback, fsevents

I'm writing an application that has to be able to monitor filesystem directories for changes in python, in order to do that i use MacFSEvents, a python wrapper over the FSEvents C API, as for obvious efficiency reasons polling can't be a choice since this code could be in charge of monitoring recursively a lot of files, the module however does work and a code like this produces the expected result

```
    from fsevents import Observer, Stream


def callback(FSEvent, mask=0, cookie=0):
        """
        the callback that gets called when an event occurs
        :param FSEvent: file or dir that originated the event
        :param mask: a bitMask that specifies the type of the event
        :param cookie: contains info to bind a moved_to to a moved_from event
        """
        print(FSEvent)
        print('\n')
        print(mask)
        print('\n')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        obs = Observer()
        obs.start()
        str = Stream(callback, "/Users/filipposavi/ass", file_events=True)
        obs.schedule(str)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        obs.stop()
        obs.join
```

however when I put that into the class that should manage (relatively) low level filesystem details the callback is not called, here below you can find the code that doesn't work

```
import hashlib
import os
import fsevents
from database import Db


BUFSIZE = 2 ** 3
chunksize = 1024


IN_CREATE = 0x00000100
IN_ATTRIB = 0x00000004
IN_MODIFY = 0x00000002
IN_DELETE = 0x00000200
IN_MOVED_FROM = 0x00000040
IN_MOVED_TO = 0x00000080


class FsCore(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.db = Db()

    def callback(self, FSEvent, mask, cookie=0):
        """
        the callback that gets called when an event occurs
        :param FSEvent: file or dir that originated the event
        :param mask: a bitMask that specifies the type of the event
        :param cookie: contains info to bind a moved_to to a moved_from event
       """
        print('ciao')
        if (mask & IN_CREATE) == IN_CREATE:
            self.on_created(FSEvent)
        if (mask & IN_ATTRIB) == IN_ATTRIB:
            self.on_attrib(FSEvent)
        if (mask & IN_DELETE) == IN_DELETE:
            self.on_deleted(FSEvent)
        if (mask & IN_MODIFY) == IN_MODIFY:
            self.on_modified(FSEvent)
        if (mask & IN_MOVED_FROM) == IN_MOVED_FROM:
            self.on_moved(FSEvent, cookie, False)
        if (mask & IN_MOVED_TO) == IN_MOVED_TO:

    def startFSEvents(self, path):
        """

        :param path:
        """
        self.observer = fsevents.Observer()
        self.observer.start()
        self.stream = fsevents.Stream(self.callback, path, file_events=True)
        self.observer.schedule(self.stream)

    def stopFSEvents(self):
        """


        """
        self.observer.unschedule(self.stream)
        self.observer.join()
        self.observer.stop()
```

and here is the code that's should be triggering the event/callback(part of a unit test)

```
    self.fs = FsCore()
    self.fs.startFSEvents(self.path)
    self.database = Db()
    path = self.path + "/tmp"
    file = open(path, mode='a')
    file.write("ciao")
    file.flush()
    file.close()
    if not self.database.getFile(path):
        self.fail("onCreated callback doesn't works or it's not called at all")
```

Hope you guys can hint me the right direction since i'm a bit of a novice with python so i'm pretty stuck on that